# Binding ListBos ItemSource to Combobox's selectedVAlue

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `ComboBox` which is Binded to a `List<String>` defined in the ViewModel.
I have as well a `ListBox` who's ItemSource depends on `SelectedValue` from the `ComboBox`.

In the ViewModel, I have the following properties:

- `List<String> ComboBoxSource`
- `string SelectedValue` (`ComboBox` selected value)
- `ObservableCollection<String> ListBoxSource`

Now, when the `ComboBox` `selectedvalue` changes, I am setting the `SelectedVAlue` property in the ViewModel(`DataContext`) explicitly which is raising a `PropertyChange` Event on `ListBoxSource` in order to update the `ListBox`.

My question is how can I do this without explicitly setting `SelectedVAlue` in ViewModel i.e Can I bind the `ComboBox.SelectedVAlue` to my `SelectedVAlue` property ?

Here is my XAML:

```
 <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ComboBoxVersions"  SelectedIndex="0" Margin="10" SelectionChanged="ComboBoxVersions_OnSelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding EnvironmentVersions}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Version " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>


    <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxEnvironments" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="300" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding Environments}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="800" >
                </WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxEnvironment" Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Margin="5">
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Here is the Code Behind:

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Handles the OnSelectionChanged event of the ComboBoxVersions control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="SelectionChangedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void ComboBoxVersions_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataContext = this.DataContext as TestRunnerControlViewModel;
        dataContext.SelectedVersion = ((ComboBox) sender).SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue` because it is more appropriate to bind, just create a `SelectedVersion` property, bind this property to the `combobox's` `SelectedItem`, whenever the SelectedItem is changed, update you ListBox itemSource in the setter of that property.

`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is necessary to let the `ListBox` know that their source has been changed

```
 private List<String> _environmentVersions;   
    public List<String> EnvironmentVersions
    {
        get
        {
            return _environmentVersions;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_environmentVersions == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _environmentVersions = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<String> _environments ;
    public ObservableCollection<String> Environments
    {
        get
        {
            return _environments;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_environments == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _environments = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private String _selectedVersion  ;
    public String SelectedVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedVersion;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedVersion == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _selectedVersion = value;
            //update your listBox itemSource 
            // ...
        }
    }
```

and in the Xaml:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ComboBoxVersions"  SelectedIndex="0" Margin="10" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVersion}" ItemsSource="{Binding EnvironmentVersions}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Version " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```